# Build project error

Tags: android-studio

I am trying Android Studio. Installed on Windows XP and got the following error 
while trying to build a new project. One of the error messages: the SDK directory is not found.
I have tried to change the path to the SDK but cannot find the option in the configuration menu. Any help is welcome

RESOLVE ERROR:

```
Failed to import new Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
Build file 'L:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\AndroidStudioProjects\Prueba3Project\Prueba3\build.gradle' line: 9
A problem occurred evaluating project ':Prueba3'.
A problem occurred evaluating project ':Prueba3'.
The SDK directory 'L:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\ConfiguraciÃ³n local\Datos de programa\Android\android-studio\sdk' does not exist.
```

Comment: I've got the same issue in ubuntu 12.10 any ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

You need to modify the `local.properties` file in your project.

I had manually point it to the path of my SDK, which for me, on Mac, looked like this:

```
sdk.dir=/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk
```